# How to get 2 counts based on two different values in list and check the two counts are equal or not?

Tags: java, list, arraylist, collections

I have a list "List issues" this list will hold all the issues from all the projects.

From this "issues" object i can get issues.Project, Issues.Status inside the loop.

I wanted to do the below mentioned operations.

```
List<Issue> issues = issueCollector.get().getAppropriateIssues();
for (int i=0;i< issues.size();i++)
{
  Issue iss = issues.get(i);                
}
```

eg:

```
**Project    IssueKey     Status**

  PRJ 1     issKey 1      Closed
  PRJ 1     issKey 2      Resolved
  PRJ 2     isskey 1      Open
  PRJ 3     issKey 1      Closed
  PRJ 3     issKey 2      Resolved
  PRJ 3     issKey 3      Closed
```

1. I wanted to get the count of issues with respect to the PROJECT and store it in a variable. How to get the values like below and store in a collection vairable?

   eg :    PROJECT | Count(Issues)

   ```
       PRJ 1        2
       PRJ 2        1
       PRJ 3        3
   ```
2. To get the count of issues in a project with the status  in closed or resolved and store it in a variable. How to get the values like below and store in a collection vairable?

   eg :
     PROJECT   | Count(Issues count whose in CLOSED or RESOLVED)

   ```
       PRJ 1         2
       PRJ 3         3
   ```

Then from this two variable, i want to check condition like

```
 if(PRJ1(2 issues) == PRJ1(2 issues(with status)))
    {
        Add this PROJECT to a LIST of STRING
            List<STRING> val = new List();
            val.add(PROJECT);
    }
```

Comment: Is the question hidden here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For flexibility, (it can be that you have to check open issues or sum of this or that), I advise to introduce a small class `IssueStatus` which keeps all project issue counts. Java 8 allows you to construct it within another class btw.

```
class IssueStatus {
   int numOfClosed = 0;
   int numOfResolved = 0;
   int numOfOpen = 0;

   // not sure if status is string or enum
   addStatusCount(String status) {
       // logic to inc the num
       // eg if "closed", then use numOfClosed++
   }

   getNumOfClosed() { return numOfClosed; }
   getNumOfResolved() { return numOfResolved; }
   getNumOfOpen() { return numOfOpen; }
   getTotalIssues() { return numOfClosed + numOfResolved + numOfOpen; }
}
```

You can consider to add a project name to the object. But here, I've used a map to associate a given status to a project.

```
Map<String, IssueStatus> issueStatusMap = new ...
```

To populate the map, just use your loop

```
for (int i=0;i< issues.size();i++) {
    Issue iss = issues.get(i);
    // check if given project is already in map -> if not, add IssueStatus instance
    if (! issueStatusMap.contains(iss.Project)) {
        issueStatusMap.put(iss.Project, new IssueStatus());
    }
    // add issue status cound
    issueStatusMap.get(iss.Project).addStatusCount(iss.Status);
}
```

You can use java 8's `stream().forEach( ... )` to fill in the map though. Now, it's easy to have statistic information from your map.

```
// now you only have to get the data simply

// 1) sum of issues
for(Map.Entry<String, IssueStatus> entry : issueStatusMap.entrySet()) {
    s.o.p("project name: " + entry.getKey() + " has " + entry.getValue().getTotalIssues());
}
// or use the sum of the three getNum... methods

// 2) count only closed + resolved
for(Map.Entry<String, IssueStatus> entry : issueStatusMap.entrySet()) {
    IssueStatus is = entry.getValue();
    s.o.p("project name: " + entry.getKey() + " status count: closed + resolved = " + (is.getNumOfClosed() + is.getNumOfResolved()));
}
```

Of course you can do all java 8's stream and group by, but I don't advise it because you have to perform another loop each time you're doing your task. This can be an exhaustive operation if the list of issues is very large.

Like in this example, if you want to get sum of counts and sum of "closed" and "resolved" issues by using `Collectors.groupingBy`, then you're going through that issue list two times. My solution requires one looping, with the cost of some extra heap space to store the objects. And when gathering the data, another small loop is used to go through all project status object instead of all issues. (if there are 100 projects with 5000 issues, then there is a big win)

Finally, to answer your last thing (I admit that this one isn't clear for me)

```
if(PRJ1(2 issues) == PRJ1(2 issues(with status)))
```

which is simply

```
IssueStatus status = issueStatusMap.get("<your projectName>");
if( status.getNum... == status.getNum... ) {
    // do something
}
```

Comment: Thanks for all your answers. yesterday I got one answer, but that is not visible now why?

Answer (score 0):

Use java8 collectors api for perform the grouping. check link https://www.mkyong.com/java8/java-8-collectors-groupingby-and-mapping-example/

Answer (score 0):

A simple approach; assuming that you actually have a *Project* class; you can use a `Map<Project, List<Issues>>` and from there:

```
Map<Project, List<Issues>> issuesByProject = new HashMap<>();
for (Issue issue : issues) {
  if (issue status ... can be ignored) {
    continue;
  }
  Project proj = issue.getProject();
  if (issuesByProject.containsKey(proj)) {
    issuesByProject.get(proj).add(issue);
  } else {
    List newListForProject = new ArrayList<>();
    newListForProject.add(issue);
    issuesByProject.put(proj, newListForProject);
  }
}
```

This code iterates your list (using the simpler and to-be-preferred for-each looping style). Then we first check if that issue needs to be processed (by checking its status for example). If not, we stop that loop iteration and hop to the next one (using *continue*). If processing is required, we check if that map contains a list for the current project; if so, we simply add that issue. If not, we create a new list, add the issue, and then put the list into the map.